# repeating values in PHP drilldown

Tags: php

I am relatively new to PHP. I have drilled down a couple of levels through a DB, and i have hit a snag. i cant work out why i am only retrieving one repeated record when there should just be 5 different ones. my code is below...

```
<?php 

    $sections = $_GET['rid'];
 // Connects to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT question_keywords.rfp_id, question_keywords.section_id, section_name FROM rfp, question_keywords, section WHERE question_keywords.rfp_id = rfp.rfp_id AND section.section_id = question_keywords.section_id AND section.section_id = '$sections'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15>";
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
<td><b>Section ID</b></td><td><b>Section Name</b></td>" ; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
      $sid = $row['section_id'];  //if you have the column names, replace 0 with 'column_name'
      $sname = $row['section_name'];
     # $status = $row['status'];

# inserts value into table as a hyperlink

echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td>$sid</td><td><a href=view_section_detail.php?sid=$sid>$sname</a></td>";
}

# displays table

print '</table>';

 ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Does your query return the expected results when run directly against the database?

Comment: be careful, your code can be injected with malicious SQL

Comment: What you saying is that you retrieve 5 records but the same one in stead of 5 different one's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you simply forgot adding two `</tr>` s 
If you have a look into the HTML-Output it should be there. Try :

```
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
<td><b>Section ID</b></td><td><b>Section Name</b></td></tr>" ;
```

and:

```
echo '</tr></table>';
```

and as a comment already stated, try querying your command against the database in a sql command (or phpmyadmin).